# How to group by and get top N in each group and other fields of the top N in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have the following documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599b1a789125130dfc613188"),
    "traj_id" : 1,
    "aisle_id" : "Aisle01",
    "traf_seq" : [ 
        {
            "node" : "catg1",
            "pst" : 1,
            "time" : 12.0
        }, 
        {
            "node" : "catg2",
            "pst" : 2,
            "time" : 12.0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599b1a789125130dfc613188"),
    "traj_id" : 2,
    "aisle_id" : "Aisle01",
    "traf_seq" : [ 
        {
            "node" : "catg1",
            "pst" : 1,
            "time" : 12.0
        }, 
        {
            "node" : "catg2",
            "pst" : 2,
            "time" : 12.0
        },
        {
            "node" : "catg1",
            "pst" : 1,
            "time" : 12.0
        }, 
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599b1a789125130dfc613188"),
    "traj_id" : 3,
    "aisle_id" : "Aisle02",
    "traf_seq" : [ 
        {
            "node" : "catg1",
            "pst" : 1,
            "time" : 12.0
        }, 
        {
            "node" : "catg2",
            "pst" : 2,
            "time" : 12.0
        },
        {
            "node" : "catg2",
            "pst" : 3,
            "time" : 12.0
        }, 
    ]
}
```

I am trying to the top N categories visited in each Aisle. Say for N = 1,
Expected output would be something like :

```
"_id" : {
    "aisle" : "Aisle01",
    "catg" : "catg1"
},
"maxValue" : 3.0


"_id" : {
    "aisle" : "Aisle02"
    "catg" : "catg2"

},
"maxValue" : 2.0
```

Since in aisle 1, catg 1 has been visited the max number of times (ie 3), and catg2 in aisle has been visited 2 times (the maximum).

I  can get the maximum count in each aisle, but I am struggling to get the category name, since I exclude it in the group by field.
OR I get the names of all the categories, which I do not want.
Below is what I have so far :

```
db.test.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$traf_seq"},
{$group: {
"_id": {
    "traj_id" :"$traj_id",
    "node": "$traf_seq.node",
    "aisle":"$aisle_id"
},
"count":{
    "$sum":1}
}},
{$group: {
"_id": {
    "sumnode":"$_id.node",
    "aisle": "$_id.aisle"},
"distcount":{
    "$sum":1},
}},
{$group: {
"_id": {
     "aisle": "$_id.aisle"},
     "otherField1":{$push:"$_id.sumnode"},        
"maxValue": {$max:"$distcount"}
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For N=1, the following should do the trick:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$traf_seq" },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "aisle": "$aisle_id",
                "node": "$traf_seq.node"
            },
            "maxvalue": { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "maxvalue": -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id.aisle",
            "maxvalue": { $first: "$maxvalue" },
            "catg": { $first: "$_id.node" }
        }
    }
])
```

If you need a different structure of the output you can use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to achieve that. Just let me know should that be the case...

For an arbitrary N, the following should get you started:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$traf_seq" },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "aisle": "$aisle_id",
                "node": "$traf_seq.node"
            },
            "maxvalue": { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "maxvalue": -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id.aisle",
            "docs": {
                $push: {
                    "maxvalue": "$maxvalue",
                    "catg": "$_id.node"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            docs: {
                $slice:
                [
                    "$docs",
                    2 // this is where you can configure you N records
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$docs" }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. it works !
Sorry I forgot to mention this in the question, but if I want to count distinct visits (say catg 1 appears twice per document per traj_id I want to count it only as 1),  where do i add ? can I just add traj_id in the group ?

Comment: NM.. i got it.. just had to add the aisle in all the groupings.. Thank you !